# FORM Submit button with text-decoration:underline via JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since it doesn't appear to be possible to apply `text-decoration: underline;` to a `form.submit` button I'm wondering if someone can quickly show me how to apply it via JS? I only know html/css/php. Onmouseover=?

```
<span onmouseover="what goes here"><input type="submit"></input></span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of course the submit button is TEXT not an image. :) Forgot to mention that. Thanks!

Comment: Input elements don't have a closing tag.

Comment: They don't _have to_ have a closing tag, but it won't break the code if you include one anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to suggest that you want to underline the button itself. If you're trying to underline a button, I suggest applying the effect to the text of the button using CSS like so:

```
input[type=submit]:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3t1j2kwm/)</kbd>

Comment: I swear I tried using this attribute selector and it didn't work. But it's working now so thanks for confirming CSS can handle it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a button instead:

```
.hoverUnderline:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

<button type="submit" class="hoverUnderline">Submit stuff</button>
```

Buttons in forms are submit buttons by default so don't actually need *type="submit"*.